# Makefile deprecated syntax

Tags: c, makefile, fortran

I'm pretty bad at writing makefiles and make is throwing me the following warning:

```
Makefile:58: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
```

I was hoping that someone couple help me sort out precisely what I was doing wrong?

```
$(MAPLE_OBJ_DIR) maple_generated_code/%.o : %.f %.h
    $(F77_COMP) %.f
```

I have a directory containing a whole bunch of generated fortran files and headers in `MAPLE_OBJ_DIR = maple_generated_code` and `F77_COMP = $(F77) -c $(F77FLAGS)`

The full relevant section of the Makefile is:

```
EXECUTABLES     = sphere_comp 
# Miscellaneous files to clean up
MISCDATAFILES   =


MAPLE_OBJ_DIR = maple_generated_code
BIN_DIR = ../bin

MAPLE_OBJS = $(addprefix $(MAPLE_OBJ_DIR)/, \
eval_chi.o eval_kappa.o \
evo_pi_test.o evo_psi_test.o \
mg_lop_ham_cstr.o mg_res_ham_cstr.o mg_relax_kappa.o  mg_res_kappa.o \
mg_lop_1d_cstr.o mg_res_1d_cstr.o mg_relax_1d.o  mg_res_1d.o \
mg_lop_sphere_cstr.o mg_res_sphere_cstr.o mg_relax_sphere.o  mg_res_sphere.o )

OBJS = sphere_comp.o utils.o \

all: $(EXECUTABLES)

$(MAPLE_OBJ_DIR) maple_generated_code/%.o : %.f %.h
    $(F77_COMP) %.f 

.c.o:
    $(CC_COMP) -c $*.c

all: $(EXECUTABLES)

sphere_comp: $(MAPLE_OBJS) $(OBJS)
    $(CC_LOAD) $(MAPLE_OBJS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o sphere_comp
    /bin/mv $(EXECUTABLES) $(BIN_DIR)
    /bin/cp *param $(BIN_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was being dumb. Writing this made me see what I was doing. I have two targets in the relevant line. It should just be:

```
maple_generated_code/%.o : %.f %.h
    $(F77_COMP) %.f
```